# Restructuring data-structure to a new Schema - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I need to restructure an already existing data structure and have no clue on how to do this the most efficient way (if I should do my own custom function or maybe use a third-party library).

The data:
There might or might not be a month or day, i.e. if the user has never entered data then the data structure would look like this `{}`.

```
2019: {        // year
  7: {         // month
    6: {       // day
      activities: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
      emotionsFelt: (3) ["Excited", "Nervous", "Happy"]
      isSpecialDay: false
      latitude: null
      locationId: null
      locationName: null
      locationProvider: null
      longitude: null
      mood: "Awesome"
      optionalDescription: ""
      rating: 5
      timestamp: "2019-07-06T18:52:38.022Z"
    },
    7: {
      activities: []
      emotionsFelt: (2) ["Excited", "Lively"]
      isSpecialDay: false
      latitude: 56.130366
      locationId: "ChIJ2WrMN9MDDUsRpY9Doiq3aJk"
      locationName: "Canada"
      locationProvider: "GM"
      longitude: -106.346771
      mood: "Awesome"
      optionalDescription: ""
      rating: 5
      timestamp: "2019-07-06T19:00:18.391Z"
    }
  }
}
```

The outcome should be:

```
2019: {        // year
  7: {         // month
    6: {       // day
      avgRating: 5,
      isSpecialDay: false,
      entries: [
        {
          activities: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
          emotionsFelt: ["Excited", "Nervous", "Happy"],
          isSpecialMoment: false,
          latitude: null,
          locationId: null,
          locationName: null,
          locationProvider: null,
          longitude: null,
          mood: "Awesome",
          optionalDescription: "",
          rating: 5,
          images: [],
          timestamp: "2019-07-06T18:52:38.022Z",
        }
      ]
    },
    7: {
      avgRating: 5,
      isSpecialDay: false,
      entries: [
        {
          activities: [],
          emotionsFelt: ["Excited", "Lively"],
          isSpecialMoment: false,
          latitude: 56.130366
          locationId: "ChIJ2WrMN9MDDUsRpY9Doiq3aJk"
          locationName: "Canada"
          locationProvider: "GM"
          longitude: -106.346771
          mood: "Awesome",
          optionalDescription: "",
          rating: 5,
          images: [],
          timestamp: "2019-07-06T18:52:38.022Z",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any tips on how I can accomplish this?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it isnt clear what you need changed in the two objects

Comment: I want the `day` object to be an array of entries and not a single entry. Mapping the current `rating` as the `avgRating`. What would you need to know it clearly?

Comment: ok make a copy of the two objects using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.Parse`, then edit the copy. to loop through the copy, use `for in`, you'll probably need nested `for in`s here. looks straightforward for me, unlesss you can specify an issue in what you have tried so far, rather than how can I accomplish this!

Comment: Well, I was trying to get some guidance because I knew I could do it with `for..ins`. It just looked a bit messy to me or maybe there was a third part lib. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested `for...in` loops, destructuring, spreading, and shorthand property notation like so:

```js
let obj = {2019:{7:{6:{activities:["one","two","three","four"],emotionsFelt:["Excited","Nervous","Happy"],isSpecialDay:false,latitude:null,locationId:null,locationName:null,locationProvider:null,longitude:null,mood:"Awesome",optionalDescription:"",rating:5,timestamp:"2019-07-06T18:52:38.022Z"},7:{activities:[],emotionsFelt:["Excited","Lively"],isSpecialDay:false,latitude:56.130366,locationId:"ChIJ2WrMN9MDDUsRpY9Doiq3aJk",locationName:"Canada",locationProvider:"GM",longitude:-106.346771,mood:"Awesome",optionalDescription:"",rating:5,timestamp:"2019-07-06T19:00:18.391Z"}}}};

for (let year in obj) {
  for (let month in obj[year]) {
    for (let day in obj[year][month]) {
      const { isSpecialDay, rating: avgRating, ...r } = obj[year][month][day];
      obj[year][month][day] = { isSpecialDay, avgRating, entries: [{ isSpecialDay, avgRating, ...r }]};
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Thank you!! I guess `for.. in` is the way.

Comment: Yes @WalterMonecke - so you can access each key inside the loop.